# Set value in form field in twig template (EasyAdmin)

Tags: symfony, twig

I use EasyAdmin in Symfony 4 and I want to set some fields in twig template to disabled true or false depends on user role.

For example

```
{{ dump(form.role.vars.disabled) }}
```

shows `true`

I want to set it to false

```
{% block entity_form %}
    {% set form.role.vars.disabled = false %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock entity_form %}
```

But I got the error

> Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block"
>   expected).

Also I tried to merge it as array but got error.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: why not do that in your form configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`merge` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html) to update values of an array or a hash. You have a deeply nested hash so you need to use the `merge` filter many times:

```
{% set form = form|merge({
    role: form.role|merge({
        vars: form.role.vars|merge({
            disabled: false
        })
    })
}) %}
```

[See TwigFiddle.](https://twigfiddle.com/vzhtoz) (I used `{{ var ? 'true' : 'false' }}` instead of `{{ dump(var) }}` because TwigFiddle doesn't support the `dump` function.)

**Update:**

The above code doesn't work in your case because the `merge` filter converts the `FormView` object to an array. You would need to create a Twig extension to change the object's property. Take a look at this similar question: [Set value of single object in multidimensional array in twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978499/set-value-of-single-object-in-multidimensional-array-in-twig-template)

Or a better approach might be to do this kind of thing in the controller (or wherever you are configuring the form) like @yceruto suggested.

Comment: I have tried the merge already. And got the error `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, array given, called in...`. It is in overridden EasyAdmin template edit.html.twig