# Set a value on a multi level array

Tags: twig

`dump(item.url.options.query)`

returns: *array (size=0)*

`{% set item = item|merge({'ref': 'xyz'}) %}`

returns: no error, *item* is now set

`{% set item.url.options.query = item.url.options.query|merge({'ref': 'xyz'}) %}`

errors: *Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected token 'punctuation'; of value '.'*

How do I set the array index *item.url.options.query*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set value of single object in multidimensional array in twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978499/set-value-of-single-object-in-multidimensional-array-in-twig-template)

Answer (score 3):

You have a deeply nested array so you need to use the `merge` filter many times:

```
{% set item = item|merge({
    url: item.urls|merge({
        options: item.url.options|merge({
            query: item.url.options.query|merge({
                ref: 'xyz'
            })
        })
    })
}) %}
```

If the `item` variable or some of the array items are objects instead of arrays, you might get an error (because the `merge` filter only works with arrays and `Traversable` objects), or the objects might get converted into arrays. If that's the case, you might want to take a look at the question DarkBee linked to.

Comment: _The merge filter only works with arrays or 'Traversable', got 'object' as first argument._: `url` appears to be an object. How should I adapt the above?

Comment: Then you can't use the `merge` filter. Take a look at the question DarkBee linked to. You need to create a custom Twig extension.

Comment: lol. Twig is so fucked up