# How to change value in this array

Tags: twig

`{% set dataSrc = [{"campgroup0":"far", "total":3},{"campgroup0":"close", "total":4},{"campgroup0":"unknow", "total":8}] %}`

I want to change total value of item 0 `{"campgroup0":"far", "total":3}`

I'm trying:
`{% set item = {"campgroup0":"far", "total":0} %} {% set dataSrc = dataSrc|merge(item) %}`
but just push another item

Comment: You can't merge numeric indices in twig. See issue [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/789)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set value of single object in multidimensional array in twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978499/set-value-of-single-object-in-multidimensional-array-in-twig-template)